# Does a non-metrizable $T_2$ space always have an open cover such that three distinct given points cannot be covered by any two elements of the cover?

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y$ be a non-metrizable Hausdorff space and $a, b, c\in Y$. Is it always possible to find an open cover $\mathcal V$ of $Y$ such that $\{a, b, c\}$ cannot be covered by the union of any two members of $\mathcal V$?

If $Y$ is a metric space, then clearly there is an open cover $\mathcal V$ consisting of $\epsilon$-balls of sufficiently small $\epsilon$ satisfying the required property. I suspect this is true even for a non-metrizable Hausdorff space, but cannot think of how one would set about proving this.

Context: I am working on a generalization of a definition called "split continuity" (e.g. [Split continuity: A different perspective](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0166864122001912)), and was naturally led to this problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you, I have added some context. Please let me know if I should add more. It is a problem that came up when I was trying to formulate a certain definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $U = Y\setminus \{a, b\}$, $V = Y\setminus \{b, c\}$ and $W = Y\setminus \{a, c\}$. Then $U\cup V\cup W = Y$, $U, V, W$ are open and union of any two of $U, V, W$ doesn't contain the third point. The only assumption we used is that our space is $T_1$ i.e. points are closed.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, if $Y$ is a Hausdorff space (metrizable or otherwise), and $a, b, c \in Y$ are distinct, then it is always possible to find an open cover of $Y$ such that no two elements of the open cover contain all three of $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Since $Y$ is Hausdorff, given any point $x$, we can always find an open neighbourhood of $x$ that does not contain a given other point $y \ne x$ — more strongly, we can find an open neighbourhood of $x$ that does not contain *any* of a given finite set of points distinct from $x$. Hence, construct the open cover as follows: Take open neighbourhoods $U_a$, $U_b$, and $U_c$ of $a$, $b$, and $c$ respectively, such that $b, c \notin U_a$, $a, c \notin U_b$, and $a, b \notin U_c$. For all $x \ne a, b, c$ take an open neighbourhood $U_x$ not containing any of $a$, $b$, and $c$. Now, the collection $\{U_a, U_b, U_c\} \cup \{\, U_x \mid x \in Y \setminus \{a, b, c\}\,\}$ is an open cover of $Y$ with the required property.

Comment: [Jakobian's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4740528/152030) is definitely the simplest and the best one. Still, I'm leaving my answer here as it seems to me to be the obvious generalisation of the $\varepsilon$-neighbourhoods proof of the metric space case.